# Pagination using category ID

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination, jquery-pagination

I am facing an issue with pagination which display details using an category ID.

Below is the database table which we are using to fetch the data. We are getting some errors and data was not printing in the page. I have added the page code in Pastebin. Where is the error I have done?

PHP page code: http://pastebin.com/EXmu5X67

Database table: http://pastebin.com/ZiBhPDTd

```
--
-- Table structure for table `plot_details`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `plot_details` (
  `plot_detailsid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `imgname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `imgname1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `imgname2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `imgname3` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `imgname4` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `locality` varchar(700) NOT NULL,
  `sqft` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `acre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cent` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sqm` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `bedroom` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `bathroom` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `owner_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `video_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `covered_area` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `feet` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `random_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `pnumber` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `url_page` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`plot_detailsid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=242 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question below is the answer

block:

**session_start();**
we need to add a session start for this to get the value to be store. so the pagination will use the session id and work on all pages